# Restore file deleted / commit by mistake

Tags: git

I just wondering if someone know how to see files in a repository.

I pushed an accidentally deleted file to a repository and I don't I'm trying to get the file restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `git revert` the commit in which you deleted the file.

If you've deleted the files on your computer but *have not actually commit those changes* you can restore locally deleted files:

`git ls-files -d | xargs git checkout --`

Comment: I try git revert, but im not getting my folder back :/

Comment: If you've actually commit the deletion, then you need to figure out which commit that happened in, and then revert the commit.

Comment: what I did, is that I commit a folder with files, and I delete that folder from my local computer, and what im trying to do is get a copy of that file from the repository

Comment: Updated my answer, sounds like you have not actually *commit* the changes

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted that folder from your working copy and you want it back, just do

```
git checkout <folder_path>
```

If you accidentally removed the folder from the tracking, committed and pushed such change, then just revert that commit, as suggested by BotskoNet in his answer

```
git revert <commit_where_this_happened>
```